# Internal Server Error 500 when attempting to get profileCardProperties via MS-Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We're attempting to leverage the ability to add more attributes to the profile card in O365 per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/add-properties-profilecard.  Unfortunately, after one of the admins attempted to add both StreetAddress and PostalCode, when running a get for the ProfileCard we now receive an Internal Server 500 error.

[https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/organization/{tenant-id}/settings/profileCardProperties](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/organization/%7Btenant-id%7D/settings/profileCardProperties)

It also will not accept a POST as well after the attempted mods.  Can the profilecard be reset?

Comment: Could you please share how did the admins add streetAddress and postalCode properties? Also share the requestid and timestamp for the failed request.

Comment: Have you looked at the FAQ for profilecard (to see if there's any alternate way exists) - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/profile-cards-in-microsoft-365-e80f931f-5fc4-4a59-ba6e-c1e35a85b501?

Comment: Outside of your application, you can try calling the get profilecard using Microsoft Graph explorer or POSTMAN as well and see still you get HTTP 500 or not. Also please be aware that when you're try adding an attribute to profile card, it takes up to 24 hours for the addition to be displayed.

Comment: A requestid and timestamp for one of the failed GETs:  Client request ID - e23d6d8d-8b93-455c-9947-2d6c93341f35; Timestamp - 2020-10-08T14:31:23.  I did try the same GET via POSTMAN and still received the 500 internal server error.

Comment: 500 error usually means a bad request call. So when your changes in the api you also have to modify your get call accordingly. I suggest to review your request and try to identify what's missing on your call. You can also add snippet code to your question and the 500 error log so helpers can assist better. Remember to stash any security sensitive information.

Comment: Sometime earlier i tested it and its working now. So please go ahead and check it out. Let us know how it goes.